# why the rmse and mse is so large using XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, regression, xgboost

I'm learning XGBoost, and the mae and rmse numbes are so large, how is that possible?

this is the code I'm using in python

```
# Create the DMatrix: housing_dmatrix
housing_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)

# Create the parameter dictionary: params
params = {"objective":"reg:linear", "max_depth":4}

# Perform cross-validation: cv_results
cv_results = xgb.cv(dtrain=housing_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=4, num_boost_round=5, metrics="rmse", as_pandas=True, seed=123)

# Print cv_results
print(cv_results)

# Extract and print final boosting round metric
print((cv_results["test-rmse-mean"]).tail(1))


    train-rmse-mean  train-rmse-std  test-rmse-mean  test-rmse-std
0    141767.535156      429.452682   142980.429688    1193.794436
1    102832.542969      322.473304   104891.392578    1223.157623
2     75872.617187      266.469946    79478.935547    1601.344218
3     57245.651367      273.625016    62411.921875    2220.149857
4     44401.297851      316.422372    51348.281250    2963.378741
    51348.28125
```

Comment: From the formula, RMSE enlarges the error and is more vulnerable to outliers

Comment: btw, If you want to observe the overall error, please check MSE; If you want to observe the overall error and its stationarity, please check RMSE

Comment: the case is not about outliers, I think you don`t understand how to interpret the metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is to interpret the metrics. First I'll explain what it stnads for:

- **MSE** stands for Mean squared error and
- **RMSE** stands for Root mean squared error

This means that both metrics depend on the size of the predicted value. If you predict number of seats in a car that varies between 2 and 7, your **RMSE** is really large. On the other hand if you predict something that varries between 1 and 100 million, the **RMSE** is really low. That is the main reason why you should use some other metric such as **MAPE** (Mean Absolute Percentage Error) that will give you value **between 0 and 1**.

Check out [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html) link for more information about MAPE and how to use it using scikit-learn.